# Como puedo hacer para que todo me lo imprima en una sola linea

Tags: c++, dev-c++

```
/*Hacer un programa que pida el nombre del alumno, apellido paterno, apellido
materno y que al final lo imprima en una sola línea */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    
main ()
{
    char nom[15];
    char apep[10];
    char apem[10];
    
    cout<<"Nombre(s) del alumno:"<<"\n";
    cin>>nom;
    cout<<"Apellido Paterno:"<<"\n";
    cin>>apep;
    cout<<"Apellido Materno:"<<"\n";
    cin>>apem;
    
    cout<<"Te llamas: "<<nom<<apep<<apem;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Hice este codigo y lo imprime pero si en dado caso el usuario teclea un espacio al momento de poner su nombre este se salta la parte de introducir el apellido paterno

Comment: Porque `cin >>` no acepta espacios. Los toma como "separadores", igual que los tabs y los saltos de linea. Si quieres que lea toda la linea tienes que usar [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Answer (score 0):

El problema te pide que el resultado esté en una línea, no cuando ingresas los datos, de la cual ya lo estás haciendo.

También, recuerda que debe ser `int main()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    
int main () // <--
{
  //...
}
```

Ahora, si quieres ingresar los datos en una línea, tendrías que omitir el `/n`, ya que esto hace un salto de línea para cada dato que ingreses:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    
int main ()
{
    char nom[15];
    char apep[10];
    char apem[10];
    
    cout<<"Nombre(s) del alumno: ";
    cin>>nom;
    cout<<"Apellido Paterno: ";
    cin>>apep;
    cout<<"Apellido Materno: ";
    cin>>apem;
    
    cout<<endl;
    
    cout<<"Te llamas: "<<nom << " " << apep << " " << apem;
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
// Nombre(s) del alumno: Julio 
// Apellido Paterno: Perez
// Apellido Materno: Gomez

// Te llamas: Julio Perez Gomez
```

Comment: Ya quedo solucionado muchas gracias por la ayuda aunque con el código proporcionado seguía saltándose el apellido paterno si daba un espacio

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Hacer un programa que pida el nombre del alumno, apellido paterno, apellido
materno y que al final lo imprima en una sola línea*/

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
 
int main()
{
   
    std::string nom,apep,apem;
    std::cout << "Nombre(s) del alumno: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, nom);
    std::cout << "Apellido Paterno: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, apep);
    std::cout << "Apellido Materno: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, apem);
    
    std::cout<<"Te llamas: "<<nom << " " << apep << " " << apem;
    
    return 0;
}
```

La solución de mi problema si a alguien le podría ayudar en un futuro es con ese código